# Out of memory when copying large database with C# / ADO.Net Entities

Tags: c#, ado.net, garbage-collection

Yet another How-to-free-memory question:

I'm copying data between two databases which are currently identical but will soon be getting out of sync.  I have put together a skeleton app in C# using Reflection and ADO.Net Entities that does this:

For each table in the source database:

- Clear the corresponding table in the destination database
- For each object in the source table

  - For each property in the source object

    - If an identically-named property exists in the destination object, use Reflection to copy the source property to the destination property

This works great until I get to the big 900MB table that has user-uploaded files in it.

The process of copying the blobs (up to 7 MB each) to my machine and back to the destination database uses up local memory.  However, that memory isn't getting freed, and the process dies once it's copied about 750 MB worth of data - with my program having 1500 MB of allocated space when the OutOfMemoryException is thrown, presumably two copies of everything that it's copied so far.

I tried a naive approach first, doing a simple copy.  It worked on every table until I got to the big one.  I have tried forcing a `GC.Collect()` with no obvious change to the results.  I've also tried putting the actual copy into a separate function in hopes that the reference going out of scope would help it get GCed.  I even put a `Thread.Sleep` in to try to give background processes more time to run.  All of these have had no effect.

Here's the relevant code as it exists right now:

```
public static void CopyFrom<TSource, TDest>(this ObjectSet<TDest> Dest, ObjectSet<TSource> Source, bool SaveChanges, ObjectContext context)
    where TSource : class
    where TDest : class {

    int total = Source.Count();
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var src in Source) {
        count++;
        CopyObject(src, Dest);

        if (SaveChanges && context != null) {
            context.SaveChanges();
            GC.Collect();
            if (count % 100 == 0) {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't include the CopyObject() function, it just uses reflection to evaluate the properties of src and put them into identically-named properties in a new object to be appended to Dest.

SaveChanges is a Boolean variable passed in saying that this extra processing should be done, it's only true on the big table, false otherwise.

So, my question: How can I modify this code to not run me out of memory?

Comment: How are you declaring/using `Source` and `Dest`?  I can't see anything based on the code provided, but I also think you need to include additional code.

Comment: @Jared: I added the function declaration

Comment: EF isn't really designed and intended for bulk operations - something like that should be done directly on the database (not via a client app and EF), I think ....

Comment: One final comment on my own question: I was unable to make a nice clean generic that would create contexts and do a low-memory copy, so the process of copying this one table did not use a generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your database context utilizes a lot of caching internally, and it's holding onto a lot of your information and preventing the garbage collector from freeing it (whether you call `Collect` or not).

This means that your context is defined at too high of a scope.  (It appears, based on your edit, that you're using it across tables.  That's...not good.)  You haven't shown where it is defined, but wherever it is it should probably be at a lower level.  Keep in mind that because of connection pooling creating new contexts is not expensive, and based on your use cases you shouldn't need to rely on a lot of the cached info (because you're not touching items more than once) so frequently creating new contexts shouldn't add performance costs, even though it's substantially decreasing your memory footprint.

Comment: Yes, I'm transferring data between two different servers, and I know that EF isn't really meant for this kind of thing.  But with the data translation that I'll have to do once this project is up and running, I'll feel much more comfortable doing it in C# than in SQL, and other than this one huge table, it's such a small DB that this isn't a problem (This table is 900MB, the entire database is less than 1GB).

Comment: @AricTenEyck I didn't say anything about not using EF or using SQL directly.  I said declare multiple contexts at a smaller scope rather than reusing a single one.

Comment: I wound up doing a new context for each item create.  The source context still grows pretty big, but it wasn't enough to run me out of memory.  If the table gets much bigger, I'll have to do it another way.  Thanks for the help.